# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - for Activity Class

Tags: android, adt, android-activity, android-viewpager

I'm calling an Activity from another. While the second one loads I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

The called action class

```
public class Entry extends Activity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

ViewPager form;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
....
form.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
...
}
}
```

The activity loads if I removed `implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and `form.setOnPageChangeListener(this)`, but with these it throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError..
```

This code was completely working with ADT16, I updated to ADT18 and got into this mess.

Comment: Do you use any additional jar files?

Comment: You need support v4 package for that linked to the project

Comment: Try `Right clicking` on your project, then `Android Tools` and finally `Add Support Library...`.

Comment: I have added the support library.., I haven't used any external jars..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Create new folder `libs` in the project and copy all the external JAR files to this folder.

Then, right click on `Project`-> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path`. Here Change the path of JAR files to `libs` folder and remove the path of extrenal jar files that you have given from computer path. After That it will Work.

*Note:** If there is already folder "lib" in your project then only change the folder name "lib" to "libs". If you are not getting my point then check this [site](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/)

Name of folder Should be `libs` not `Libs`

Answer (score 1):

The [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) classes are from the version 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) libraries. Your project isn't finding them so something is not configured properly. The first place to check is **"Project Settings" -> Android**, and make sure either 4.0 or 4.0.3 is checked for your Project Build Target.

Sometimes, even though you have one of those selected, eclipse still uses an older library. The two places to check are:

1. Your **AndroidManifest.xml** file. Make sure you have `android:versionCode="4"` in the main manifest, and `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />` (at least 14)
2. Then check your **project.properties** file and make sure you have: `target=android-14`.

There's also a way to add the extra 4.0 features to older platforms by including `support-v4.jar` file in your libs directory.

One of the above options should solve your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a second class which required a jar. I checked the libs folder and found that this jar was not copied to libs folder. Hence whenever I tried to launch this second activity it gave me the NoClassDefFoundError. Just copied the jar in the libs folder and the problem was solved.